# Would psychology question be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I think well-asked psychology question does attract experts, but do we want that kind of question in our site? It seems that we accept question about [how a person with neurodivergent/disorder should do in a particular situation](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/86), but do we want to have a long tail on psychology specifically? Below is two excerpts of such question, taken from Cognitive Stack Exchange:

> ## [What makes a personality of rapid anger outburst?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/12699/12937)
>
> Within a certain time after a relationship starts, 6 months to 4 years an otherwise very desirable woman starts to have explosive anger outbursts over trivial issues and big issues alike. The words spoken and faults given during these temper outbursts does not matter, yet they follow a remarkably similar pattern...

> ## [Does a stable self actually exist in borderline people, especially artistic ones?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/17560/12937)
>
> As in my understanding, person with borderline personality disorder (BPD), in order to coping their childhood abuse, developed dissociation defense mechanism and a high sensation to read other's emotion. With that sensation, they tend to have higher creativity and successful in areas such as art, music, literature. Together with the dissociation, they are like chameleon changing their self to the environment...

Comment: FYI: in American English, "psychopath(y)" has a very negative connotation; it sounds like you're calling someone a serial killer. "Mental illness" is generally considered acceptable for most situations, but folks with Asperger's often do not consider themselves ill, preferring to be called things like "neurodivergent."

Answer (score 3):

### No

Despite my "let's give it a try" attitude to most things, I still feel as though we shouldn't. The site should focus on the interactions between you and another person(s), rather than discussing psychology. Both those mentioned questions I feel are off topic as they aren't about real life situation people find themselves in, and that, in my opinion, is that this se is mostly about.

Answer (score 2):

### Does the question involves "*interpersonal*"?

This is Interpersonal Skills Stackexchange. By definition, interpersonal means how you interact with other people.

As long as the question is affecting interpersonal relationship, I don't see why a "psychological" question is off-topic here. There will be overlaps with other sites.

Example: [My question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-can-i-explain-my-reduced-social-activity-when-depression-is-stigmatised) involves `depression`.

Some easy way to recognize if it's on topic in our site is the keywords: `friend, family, stranger`. (Although not a 100% guarantee)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like your questions from the other site because they are too "abstract," and basically geared to professionals from another discipline.

A "psychology" question can be on topic if it deals with interpersonal issues that you have actually dealt with. For instance, I asked an upvoted question on ["mirroring,"](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/63/what-impact-does-mirroring-have-on-other-people), which is something I have done, observed, and wondered about.

If you have actually observed or dealt with "rapid anger outburst" or "borderline instability," you should be able to ask a question with sufficient granularity and context to make it on topic for this site. If you haven't, then leave to it the experts on say, Cognitive SE.

Answer (score 0):

### No

Questions about psychology and not about interpersonal *skills* belong on the cognitive sciences stack exchange.

Answer (score -1):

I think a question about how to interact with a person with a psychological condition should be on-topic, as should a question on how to interact with people while having a psychological condition.

I don't think your example questions should be on-topic; they deal with people in the abstract, not individuals and their relations.

The key distinction is the "interpersonal" in "Interpersonal Skills;" we should be dealing in how people relate to each other.